# VBA How to perform a calculation using offset(x,x) minus offset(x,x).=value.copy

Tags: excel, vba

I need to perform a calculation in my code, although it has to be done with offsets e.g. `cel.Offset(8, 0)- cel.Offset(4, 0)=value.copy`

```
StringDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Now), "yyyymm")
Set SrchRng = GNL.Sheets("sheet cat").Range("M2:BZ2")
For Each cel In SrchRng
If cel.Value = StringDate Then


'need to performa calculation offset 8 minus offset 4

cel.Offset(8, 0).Copy

**‘ideally I would need something along the lines of (it is a crude example!):**
```

"cel.Offset(8, 0)- cel.Offset(4, 0)" =something, then I need this something copied (and pasted in as value in a different sheet - like in the code below)

```
End If
Next cel


Set SrchRngCF = d.Range("C1:BZ1")
For Each celCF In SrchRngCF
If celCF.Value = DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Now)), 1) Then
celCF.Offset(3, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next celCF
```

My code is searching for a date - 1, then it finds it and then I want offset 8 minus offset 4 (which equals 99000, now I need this result to be pasted in

```
celCF.Offset(3, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues)
```

[image]

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question, it's not clear?

Comment: which part is not clear SJR?

Comment: You can't assign a value to an expression(calculation) so what are you trying to do here 'cel.Offset(8, 0)- cel.Offset(4, 0)=value.Copy'

Comment: ^ What he said.

Comment: @freeflow this is just a crude example of what I want to achieve - I need a VBA expert to show me/advise how to perform something similar - perhaps a different method (although within this For loop I have)

Comment: Do you want to `copy` the cells of the range `cel.offset(8,0)` *across* to `cel.offset(4,0)` - in that case you'll want something like: `Range(cel.Offset(8, 0), cel.Offset(4, 0)).Copy`

Comment: no, I dont want to copy, I want to subtract value of offset 4 from offset 8 cells and the result of this copied to a different sheet - see my question as I have amended it

Comment: You can just do `range("A1").value=cel.Offset(8, 0)- cel.Offset(4, 0)`.

Comment: @SJR I'll try this in a moment - please see updated question with a photo

Comment: @SJR I'm getting an error 91 object variable or with block not set

Comment: An error on what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to copy the result of the subtraction, it can simply be assigned to the target range: `targetOnDifferentSheet.Value = cel.Offset(8, 0).Value - cel.Offset(4, 0).Value`.

Then in your code it would be something like this where `targetOnDifferentSheet` is just an example, in your case you want to make it dynamic.

```
Option Explicit

Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim targetOnDifferentSheet As Range

Set SrchRng = Worksheets(1).Range("M2:BZ2")
Set targetOnDifferentSheet = Worksheets(2).Range("A1")

For Each cel In SrchRng

    targetOnDifferentSheet.Value = cel.Offset(8, 0).Value - cel.Offset(4, 0).Value

Next cel
```